# Physical File Path

Tags: c#, file-io

What is the best way to get the physical path to a file in C#?

UPDATE:

I have a file name but I don't want to hard code the path to it since it may change. I just know its relative path but not its physical path.

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer your question. Can you explain in more detail what you're looking for?

Comment: I have a file name but I don't want to hard code the path to it since it may change. I just know its relative path but not its physical path.

Comment: +1 to @Marc Gravell and @Mitchell Petrotta.  I've been developing in .Net since the Beta and I have never ran across the System.IO.Path object.  Talk about learning something new every day, I should have known about this years ago.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For regular apps, [`Path.GetFullPath(path)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx) will return this. If this is web, then [`MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) is what you want (for example, `Server.MapPath("~/foo/bar")`).

Re comments; try `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(...)`;  in the absense of `HttpServerUtility` (comments), then try [`VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.virtualpathutility.toabsolute.aspx).

Comment: I'm unable to use MapPath since the constructor to HttpServerUtility is internal :(

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for a a file's absolute path, you want [System.IO.Path.GetFullPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx):

> Returns the absolute path for the
>   specified path string.

```
string path = "hello.txt";
Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFullPath(path));
```

In my opinion, the `Path` class is incredibly useful and woefully underused.

Answer (score 3):

The question is still unclear, but I'll take a shot...

If this is in Asp.Net, you can use [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632.aspx) as in

```
string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/SomeAppRelativeDirectory/SomeFile.ext");
```

In a WinForms or Console app, if the file is relative to the executable, you can try to use [System.Environment.CurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory.aspx)
as in

```
string fullPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory, "SomeAppRelativeDirectory/SomeFile.ext");
```

Comment: What assembly is that part of?

Comment: Both are in the standard class libraries.. The first in System.Web and the next in System.IO.

Comment: I guess not available in .NET 2.0

Comment: @LB; both MapPath and most of the various Path methods go back to 1.1